# Microsoft Entra ID Swagger authentication

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-entra-id

I have an API with Swagger and the authorization happens via Microsoft Entra Id. This is working but only on Firefox. When I click Authorization button in Swagger the Edge and Chrome browsers are keep waiting for something but nothing happens.
CORS is enabled: policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
Swagger registration redirectURL is https://localhost:7215/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html

**UPDATE**

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "tenentid",
    "ClientId": "clientid",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
  },
  "SwaggerAzureAD": {
    "AuthorizationUrl":       
 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenentid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenUrl": 
 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenentid/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "Scope": "api://clientid/access_as_user",
    "ClientId": "swaggerclientid"
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
  JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
    new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Swagger API",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "Oauth2.0 which uses AuthorizationCode flow",
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "name",
            Email = "email",
        }
    });

  c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
  {
    Description = "Oauth2.0 which uses AuthorizationCode flow",
    Name = "oauth2.0",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(config.SwaggerAzureAD.AuthorizationUrl),
            TokenUrl = new Uri(config.SwaggerAzureAD.TokenUrl),
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {config.SwaggerAzureAD.Scope, "Access API as User"}
            }
        }
    }
  });

  c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
  {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id="oauth2"}
        },
        new []{config.SwaggerAzureAD.Scope}
    }
  });
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
  options.OAuthClientId(config.SwaggerAzureAD.ClientId);
  options.OAuthUsePkce();
  options.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
});
```

**UPDATE 2**
AADSTS7000215 error is solved when in the appsetings.json I modified client secret declaration in AzureAD section from

```
"ClientSecret": "xxxxx"
```

to

```
"ClientCredentials": [
  {
    "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxx"
  }
]
```

Unfortunately Chrome and Edge stop me after authorization.

**UPDATE 3**
The problem with the Chrome and Firefox only occurs on my machine. I think it can be problem with Group Policy.

Comment: sorry I couldn't reproduce your issue in my side and my configuration worked well. Could you pls share more about your configurations for troubleshooting?

Comment: Do you have any else update on this question?

Comment: I do not cope with it. Authorization works on Firefox but the process is stuck in Edge and Firefox. It doesn't come back after I click on the Authorization button. My second problem is when I want to try to get data from WeatherForecastController. It gives an AADSTS7000215 error but I have already checked the settings at least 1000 times.

Comment: `the process is stuck in Edge and Firefox` -> both edge and chrome use chrome core now so I'm afraid there's something wrong with the browser, maybe an update of the browsers/restart the PC could help...It's weird. and the second problem `AADSTS7000215` which indicating `Invalid client secret` is related to the aad app, maybe create a new AAD app for testing purpose is deserved to try.

Comment: it looks like, the issue already solved right? problem one for pc policy, problem two for wrong client secret. that's good anyway to find out the issue.

Comment: Yes, it is solved. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: that's fine and thank you for your confirm : )

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this blog](https://www.josephguadagno.net/2022/06/03/enabling-user-authentication-in-swagger-using-microsoft-identity) to test in my side and it worked in chrome or firefox.

[image]
[image]

Here's what I did in my side.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {
                        "api://aad_app_id/Tiny.Read", "API permission description"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List < string > ()
        }
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
        options.OAuthClientId("client_id");
        options.OAuthClientSecret("client_secret");
        options.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}
```

And my appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

I just add `Authorize` attribute into my controller, so that without authentication, I would get 401 error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Tiny Wang. What seret do you here: options.OAuthClientSecret("22C8Q~fdrNFA1IqSVNUIjRkoYL-ojj4qa9rPFagF"); Is it the API's secret or Swagger registration's secret, please?

Comment: yes, that's the client secret which is generated in Azure AD

Comment: Super, I have another error which was not yet:  'Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app'.

Comment: this error occurred when we are using the client secret to generate the access token, so pls make sure that you are using the correct client secret in `options.OAuthClientSecret("")`, the client secret should be the one you generate for the azure ad app which id is the one you set in the `appsettings.json`.

Comment: you are now exposing an api in an Azure AD app which might not be the one you used for authentication. the client secret we used is not for the app which exposed api, but the app which added the api permission.